# If CHAR_BIT != 8, what is the size of other types?

Tags: c, sizeof

The C standard mandates `sizeof(char)` to be **1**, no matter how many bits it actually takes.
Are other data-types measured in terms of *bytes* or *chars* in case these are not the same?
Basically, assuming `CHAR_BIT` is **16**, would `sizeof(int16_t)` be equal to **1** or **2**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Basically, assuming CHAR_BIT is 16, would sizeof(int16_t) be equal to 1 or 2

Size of objects (as yielded by `sizeof` operator) is measured in bytes and a *byte* in C has `CHAR_BIT` bits.

> (C99, 6.2.6.1p4) "Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of n x CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes."

`int16_t` type if present has a width of exactly 16-bit and no padding. This means if `CHAR_BIT == 16`, then `sizeof (int16_t) == 1`

Comment: Accepted, thank you for the quote from C99-stdandard

Comment: @EOF: more generally, **the number of bits of storage (including padding) for any type is `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT`**.  For types that are allowed to have padding (not including `unsigned char` or the exact-width-and-size types), you'd need to check their range limits.

Answer (score 12):

If `CHAR_BIT` is 16 and `int16_t` exists, then `sizeof(int16_t) == 1`.  The `int8_t` type would not exist, because everything in C must be measurable in bytes (and on this system, each byte would be 16 bits... this is why the term "octet" is more precise than "byte").

There are DSP systems and old supercomputers (earlier Cray systems) where `short`, `int`, `long` all have the same size, say 64 bits.

Comment: "octet" is not "more precise" than "byte". It's *different.*

Comment: @H2CO3: "Octet" is more precise because it requires less contextual information.

Comment: I figured it had to be that way, I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

There are no limitations on the sizes of types; they only have to be able to represent a minimum range of *values*. It's perfectly legitimate, say, for a platform to have *all* its fundamental types be 64 bit wide and `sizeof` of each of them would be `1`.

Since arrays require contiguous storage, and adjacent array elements must be accessible without inventing writes, a platform may have to choose "large `char`s" to accommodate for the smallest unit of memory it can address independently.

Comment: That would apply to `int_least16_t`, but not to `int16_t`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @H2CO3: `int16_t` is a typedef, not a type. It's defined if a suitable type exists.

Comment: I know, but it can't be, say, 32 bits wide, right? (whereas `int_least16_t` **could**)

Comment: @H2CO3: That's right. The typedefs are optionally defined if a suitable type exists; there are further requirements (no padding, sign representation). I reworded it to be explicit about fundamental types, though.